# How to convert world contact positions to robot's local coordinate?

Tags: gazebo, contact

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am implementing contact plugin on PR2. I found the contact sensor returns contact positions based on world coordinate.

Since robot can move around and my controller only accepts contact positions based of torso_lift_link coordinate, I need to convert the position from world to local. Is there any method for it?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/614/how-to-convert-world-contact-positions-to-robot%27s-local-coordinate?/) by [Daehyung Park](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/114/daehyung-park/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 47 on 2013-01-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Take the difference between the robot pose and the contact pose.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Daehyung Park](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/114/daehyung-park/) on 2013-01-13**:
I found example from ros gazebo bumper plugin. Finally, it works. Thanks.